# How do i upload files in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, file, selenium, xpath, upload

I launched a browser in a remote PC and I want to import a zip file from the local folder in that remote PC to my web application. When i click Import button it redirects me to a File Upload that does not show me any xpath for that frame. I tried to get the xpath of Import Button and use send_keys of that local file path to that object like below,

```
importbutton=driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*@id='templateUploadButton_label']/img")
importbutton.send_keys("C:/../pathtofile")
```

but it gives me an error like this

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   cannot focus element

However, when i perform importbutton.click() it opens up the file upload frame.

Manual steps being : Click Import --> Opens up File Upload frame and I chose a local path and click Open, It shows up a dialog box if we can proceed to upload and I hit YES.

Answer (score 0):

```
.//*@id='templateUploadButton_label']/img
```

You are trying to send keys to an `img` element, not the `input` - hence the error.

Change your locator to target the `input` element with `type="file"`.

Comment: Hi, I have taken the correct one now and it worked when i launched driver from server, file path being the path in server. But when i launched the driver in remote it says me File Not Found error. I changed to locations under C: and Desktop but the file is not getting uploaded.